# Blocking IP Address by Iptable

Tags: linux, security, iptables

i want to block ever ip addresses that have 50 connection per min . what am i going to do ? should i write a basic code ? 
Thanks in Advance .

Answer (score 1):

Look at this [Debian Administration](http://www.debian-administration.org/articles/187) article on rate limiting connections.  Or look at this http://www.shorewall.net/Actions.html#Limit.

Answer (score 0):

I also had some brute attacks from a certain IP, here is how I blocked the IP via iptables.

(1) edit iptables

> vi /etc/sysconfig/iptables

(2) add a line on the top of -A list (if you add it in the lower part, there is a chance it might not work because earlier conditions are met so the packets you are trying to block are still allowed to go through... I had this problem in the beginning and finally found the reason)

> -A INPUT -s xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx -j DROP

(3) restart iptables

> /etc/init.d/iptables restart

That's it. Finally I don't see the connection messages in the server log anymore.

I also found people are saying to use 'fail2ban'. You may want to try it if there are multiple IPs (& changing) trying to connect to your server.

Answer (score 0):

I think I had to install iptables from source to get the higher number of hits to work correctly..

```
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp -m state --state NEW -m recent --set --name TCPRATE --rsource
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp -m state --state NEW -m recent --update --seconds 60 --hitcount 50 --name TCPRATE --rsource -j LOG --log-prefix "TCP Rate Exceeded: "
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp -m state --state NEW -m recent --update --seconds 60 --hitcount 50 --name TCPRATE --rsource -j DROP
```